# JavaScript unhackable countdown timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, countdown

I'm currently working on a quizz app. When a question appears the users has 10 seconds to answer it, otherwise they don't get the points for that question. Once the timer is up, I want to autmatically move to the next question. I am currently facing issues on how to make the 10 second countdown timer "unhackable" by the client.

My initial idea was to use something along the lines of `setTimeout()` on the client-side for 10 seconds, and once the timer is complete, ask the server to fetch the next question. The problem with this is that the client-side timer *can* be hacked/modified to run for longer than 10 seconds, potentionally giving some users longer than 10 seconds to answer the question.

```
client <--- sends question --- server
  |
start timer for 10 seconds (as this is client-side, it could easily be extended)
  |
  .
10 seconds later 
  .
  V
client --- ask for next question / send answer ---> server
```

In order to keep it unhackable, I thought of moving the time checking logic to the sever-side. This would involve keeping two variables (`A` and `B`) on the server-side per connected user, one representing the time the question was sent, and the other representing the time an answer was given. The client-side timer would still run, except the server side uses the time-stamps to perform some validation to check if the difference between the timestamps A and B exceeds 10 seconds:

```
client <--- sends question --- server (send question at timestamp `A`)
  |
start timer for 10 seconds (as this is client-side, it could easily be extended)
  |
  .
10 seconds later 
  .
  V
client --- ask for next question / send answer ---> server (receive request at timestamp `B`)
                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
v
server logic:
  duration = B - A
  if(duration > 10 seconds) {
    // allocated time exceeded
  }
```

However, I see a few potentional flaws with this. The time it takes for the question to arrive to the client from the server and the time between when the server sent the questioon (time `A`) to the time that the client-side timer starts won't be instentationous and will depend on the ping / connection that the user has to the server. Similar ping issues exist when the client asks for the next question. Moreover, I'm worried that if the client-side timer which is supposed to run for 10 seconds lags behind a little, then it would also cause the server-side check to fail. As a result, checking if the duration exceeded 10 seconds isn't enough, and it would require some additional buffer. However, I feel like arbitarly hard-coding the buffer to something like 1 or 2 seconds could potentionally still lead to issues and feels like a bit of a hacky work-around that isn't very robust.

**Question:** I'm wondering if there is a different approach that I am missing to keep the client side timer unhackable and accurate. I also want to try and avoid creating seperate timers with `setTimeout()` or alike for each connected user on the server-side, as many users could be connected at one given point in time, and having so many timers queued up on the server feels unresourceful. I also want to try and keep the number of messages sent back and forth between the client and the server to a minimum.

Comment: If the client has a bad internet connection, that's their problem and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Why don't you require the answer to be posted to the server within 10 seconds of when the web page was served (or perhaps add 1 or 2 more seconds of grace period).  Then, the enforcement is entirely on the server.  You're app just isn't going to work if delivery of a simple web page is taking multiple seconds anyway.

Comment: There is no way to prevent hacking of any client-side time measures.  That's why you HAVE to use server-side measurement.

Comment: use a web socket, on connect server sets up state and sends a question, client emits the answer, the server can reject if took longer than 10 seconds, server can emit after 10 seconds to set the state or the current question. it can't be hacked if the client is just displaying what the server sends and within 10 seconds the client must reply, all timing is done serverside, your using node it should be trivial to implement

Answer (score 1):

What about a cookie?

Set a cookie with a unique token. Set its expiration to now()+15 seconds. Save the token and time on server side. Keep your client-side timer running with an auto submit after 10 seconds.

When the answer comes in, if there is no cookie... It certainly means the answer was sent after the delay (and the timer was hacked).

So a cookie expiration time of now() + 10 seconds + a grace period of ~5 additionnal seconds is supposed to be way enought to compensate the HTTP delays.

If they hack the timer, the cookie should have expired (and deleted). If they also hack the cookie expiration(!), anyway the token will be used to retreive the question sent datetime and you will compare it with the answer received datetime.

Comment: Cookies are still a client-side technology and still hackable.

Comment: That is what I said... But anyway, it is used to retreive the sent time. The two datetime are established on server-side.

Comment: You may as well just keep the sent time in a server-side client session object.  I see no value in using a cookie to store that time at all - it just makes things more complicated.  A cookie is required for the server-side session object, but it only has a session ID in it (and will usually be encrypted too), nothing related to the timing so nothing related to the timing is hackable via that cookie.

Comment: Exactly...  The cookie only should contain a token (or a session id). That is what I suggested...

Comment: Well, I'm suggesting something entirely different than you.  You are basing your entire logic on the expiration of a cookie which is under the client control and thus hackable.  I'm saying that you require the presence of a cookie to identify the client (no cookie, no service), but all the timing data is stored on the server only and the cookie is used only to identify which client this is and thus which stored timing on the server is theirs.  One could simply use express-session for the cookie and store the timing the server-side session object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting the clock on the server when the question is sent. You could start the clock on the server when the question is shows to the user (on the client).

- Maintain 2 clocks one on the client other on the server.
- Timestamp every time sensitive request (`Start quiz timer` and `End quiz timer` and check if the timestamp discrepancy is within acceptable tolerance.

[image: Quiz app synchronisation problem]